# strictNullChecks errors on Passport

Tags: typescript, passport.js

I have a passport middleware that uses callbacks. When I call the callback after a user has successfully authenticated, the callback is called of the form:

```
done(null, user);
```

Typescript throws an error that `null` is not is not the same type as `Error`.
Is there a way around this?
I'm using the `strictNullChecks` flag.

Comment: Can you link to the definition file that you're using?

Comment: `@types/passport` from npm

Comment: Well, based on this: https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/blob/354cec620daccfa0ad167ba046651fb5fef69e8a/types/passport/index.d.ts looks like `err: any`, so you shouldn't have this problem

Comment: I think the problem had to do with how I defined my check database function: `verifyUser (done: (error: Error, user: user| boolean ,  options: any)=>void) `

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, if you define it like so:

```
done: (error: Error, user: user| boolean , options: any) => void
```

Then you must pass an `Error` like so:

```
done(new Error(), user);
```

If you want to be able to pass `null` then just change it to:

```
done: (error: Error | null, user: user| boolean , options: any) => void
```